# Uncaught SyntaxError in RWD theme when using double quote (") as configurable attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, rwd-theme

When using the RWD theme with configurable products that have associated products with a size option using double *quotes* (") I am getting an error that is shown below.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string.

This does not occur if I switch back to the default theme.

Does it sound like it is not being escaped properly?

The error appears in the console as follows:-

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 23 of the JSON data
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
Line 2
```

[Error screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/gs8ohu4r7/)

Update: I have managed to fix this issue by using the **addslashes** function which successfully escapes the JSON output.

The file affected is: app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml

Line 35 was:

```
ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(<?php echo $imageFallback['product']->getId(); ?>, $j.parseJSON('<?php echo $imageFallback['image_fallback']; ?>'));
```

Changed to:

```
ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(<?php echo $imageFallback['product']->getId(); ?>, $j.parseJSON('<?php echo addslashes($imageFallback['image_fallback']); ?>'));
```

I am not aware whether this is a bug in the code or not, but it worked when implemented into the Ultimo Magento theme as well as RWD.

Comment: It does sound like things aren't being escaped correctly. What page does this happen on? - As a whole, using double quotes (") as an attribute label is pretty risks. While Magento might be well tested, any module developer or theme developer that doesn't test for this is likely to introduce these kinds of bugs.

Comment: This is happening on the product page when the configurable options are displayed.  
I now realise that using double quotes would have avoided this issue but it should really be possible.  
We sell clothing and being able to represent the size for inches as a " is important for us rather than having to use the word 'inch'.  
We are also in the position where our products are linked to marketplaces which mean we cannot now change the products configurable options.  
Not sure how to move this forward. Is there a way to get some help with this?

Comment: What file and line is throwing that error?

Comment: added error to original post

Comment: Please add original JSON and more context. What do you expect, where comes the JSON data from, place the code which generates the JSON, etcetera

Comment: Updated post to show fix that I implemented.